# Why does clang allow this C-style cast in a constexpr?

Tags: c++, clang, constexpr

The following code compiles with clang++ 14 but not with g++ 12 (which fails because `reinterpret_cast` is not allowed in constexprs).

```cpp
constexpr int* convert(char* a) {
    return (int*)(a);
}

int main() {
    return (int) *convert(new char('a'));
}
```

Why does clang allow this C-style cast while gcc doesn't?

Comment: That is almost certinly undefined behavior anyway!

Comment: Does it compile with clang++ 17.0.6?

Comment: @Eljay It does: https://godbolt.org/z/Gsf8zaKcT. There seems to be a difference between C++20 and C++23 in gcc tho.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Still with a little bit more constexpr, there are errros : https://godbolt.org/z/jM8Tce7M9

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Before [P2448R2](https://wg21.link/P2448R2#pnum_24), if a `constexpr` function could never produce a constant expression no matter what the arguments, your program would be ill-formed, no diagnostic required. This is standardese for "A compiler is allowed to check but doesn't have to", especially for something hard to prove.

Your function fits that definition: no argument for `a` would mean that `convert(a)` would be a constant expression. GCC chose to check this specific case and Clang did not.

After P2448R2, this rule was struck and it is no longer ill-formed. The function is now a `constexpr` function that just can't be called at compile time, exactly as if it was not marked `constexpr`.

Your current code does have undefined behaviour, but it wouldn't have undefined behaviour if you had instead had `new char[sizeof(int)]{}` or `(char*) new int{}`.

And according to https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html, P2448R2 is implemented in GCC 14 (the development branch). And sure enough your code compiles now with GCC 14.